# Defining counter including section or chapter

Tags: cross-referencing, environments

In the following LaTeX code I want the referring number of the `nlpr` environment to appear as the referring number of the theorem.
How shall I modify the definition of the `nlpr` environment?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newcounter{prnum}[section]
\newenvironment{nlpr}
{
    \refstepcounter{prnum}
    \begin{description}
        \setlength{\itemindent}{-4.5mm} 
        \item[\arabic{prnum}.]
}
{
    \end{description}
}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\begin{thm}\label{thm1}
    This is the first theorem.
\end{thm}

\begin{nlpr}\label{pro1}
    This is the first problem.
\end{nlpr}

From the \ref{thm1}, problem \ref{pro1} is clearly solved.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sebastiano for your careful edit.

Comment: :-) When I was a newbie the best users (I'm not good with LaTeX) have taught me how to edit. I do the same with pleasure for you. You are welcome in our community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\newcounter{<cntr>}[<within>]` will reset `<cntr>` whenever `<within>` is stepped. In your case the `prnum` counter will be reset with every section. However, the representation doesn't include the `section` counter itself. To include it (similar to what the `theorem` counter includes), you should change `\theprnum`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\newcounter{prnum}[section]
\renewcommand{\theprnum}{\thesection.\arabic{prnum}}% <--------------

\newenvironment{nlpr}{%
  \refstepcounter{prnum}%
  \begin{description}
    \setlength{\itemindent}{-4.5mm}%
    \item[\theprnum.]
}{%
  \end{description}
}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\begin{thm}\label{thm1}
  This is the first theorem.
\end{thm}

\begin{nlpr}\label{pro1}
  This is the first problem.
\end{nlpr}

From Theorem \ref{thm1}, Problem \ref{pro1} is clearly solved.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many many thanks to your quick and correct response!

Comment: Also `\newcounter{prnum}\counterwithin(prnum}{section}` would work.

Comment: @egreg: Since when were `\counterwithin` and `\counterwithout` included in the kernel?

Comment: April 2018, `texdoc ltnews28`

Comment: Thanks @egreg for your comment. I'll try it also.